# How to exclude metaClass from request model in swagger ui

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui, restful-url, swagger-2.0

I am getting something "metaClass": {} in request in swagger ui.html. How to exclude this.

```
 {
      "Maps": [
        {
          "List": [
            {
              "key": "string",
              "metaClass": {},
              "type": "string",
            }
          ],
          "key": "string",
          "metaClass": {}
        }
      ],
      "metaClass": {},
      "output": "string"
    }
```

Comment: Do you write the OpenAPI (Swagger) definition manually or are you generating it from code? If the former - post the contents of your OpenAPI YAML or JSON file. If the latter - post your code and specify which framework you are using.

Comment: i have wrriten manually. By the way i got the solution. Need to use Docker.ignoredParameterTypes(groovy.lang.MetaClass.class)